# Dataframe column of arrays to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe `df` with a single column that contains arrays of length 3. Now, I want to transform this column to a numpy array of the correct shape. However, applying `np.reshape` does not work. How can I do this?

Here is a brief example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col'])
for i in range(10):
    df.loc[i,'col'] = np.zeros(3)

arr = np.array(df['col'])
np.reshape(arr, (10,3)) # This does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches using `np.vstack` and `np.concatenate` -

```
np.vstack(df.col)
np.concatenate(df.col).reshape(df.shape[0],-1) # for performance
```

For best performance, we could use the underlying data with `df.col.values` instead.

Sample run -

```
In [116]: df
Out[116]: 
         col
0  [7, 5, 2]
1  [1, 1, 3]
2  [6, 1, 4]
3  [7, 0, 0]
4  [8, 8, 0]
5  [7, 8, 0]
6  [0, 5, 8]
7  [8, 3, 1]
8  [6, 6, 8]
9  [8, 2, 3]

In [117]: np.vstack(df.col)
Out[117]: 
array([[7, 5, 2],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [6, 1, 4],
       [7, 0, 0],
       [8, 8, 0],
       [7, 8, 0],
       [0, 5, 8],
       [8, 3, 1],
       [6, 6, 8],
       [8, 2, 3]])
```